# WCF dual binding hosting in IIS

Tags: iis, wcf

i am trying to host a service in IIS which has 2 methods... 1 of them can also be accesed via a simple HTTP-GET request...

This is my config:

```
  <service name="Svc.PaymentService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address="PaymentService.svc/"
              bindingName="Http"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="httpBinding"
              contract="Svc.IPaymentService" />
    <endpoint address="WEBGETPaymentService.svc/"
              behaviorConfiguration="EndpointWebGetBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="Svc.IPaymentService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

the content auf the SVC files is just a simple redirect to my classes

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Svc.PaymentService"  %>
<%@ Assembly Name="MyService" %>
```

and the interface looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    string SOAPMethod(
        string test);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "asdf?test={test}")]
    string RESTfulMethod(
        string test);
```

When i am trying to host the service in IIS and call it via HTTP-GET Request, i always receive a 404...

http://localhost/MyService/WEBGETPaymentService.svc/RESTfulMethod/asdf?test=hello

Anyway, when i try to call the SOAP method via PaymentService.svc it works...

Any ideas what the mistake is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in order to use the webHttpBinding, you need to use the `WebServiceHost` (see [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx)) in your REST based *.svc file.

So your WEBGETPaymentService.svc should look like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="True" 
    Service="Svc.PaymentService"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"  %>
```

so in that case, it will then use the `WebServiceHost` and do all the necessary magic to make REST possible in WCF.

Also check out the [WCF REST developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) on MSDN for more info on how to host and use WCF REST services.

Comment: mhm, it didn't solve my problem.. now i get a "No eservice endpoint defined", but i am quite sure the definition is correct...

Comment: what URL do you use? Based on your config, it would have to be something like `http://localhost/MyService/WEBGETPaymentService.svc/asdf?test=abc` - are you missing part of that URL, maybe??